# Batch update Kendo UI Grid Changing values dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, datasource

I have this Kendo ui grid bind to a table. This grid have Batch edit features active. It means that I can change values directly on the grid cells and save it.

What I would like to accomplish is running a loop thru each line change the displayed values in some columns on the client side and then hit the save button.

This is what I have in my grid:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TokenEncrypt.Models.SellerEntity>()
  .Name("grid")

  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
      columns.Bound(c => c.EntityId);
      columns.Bound(c => c.SellerEntityTypeId);
      columns.Bound(c => c.CompanyId);
      columns.Bound(c => c.IsActive);
      columns.Bound(c => c.AwsAccessKeyId);
      columns.Bound(c => c.SecretAccessKey);
  })
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 500px;" })
  .Scrollable()      
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
  .ToolBar(toolbar =>
  {
       toolbar.Save();
  })


  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .Read(read => read.Action("SellerEntities_Read", "Grid"))
      .Update(update => update.Action("SellerEntities_Ubdate", "Grid"))
      .Batch(true)
      .Model(model =>

      {
          model.Id(c => c.EntityId);
      }
      )

      )

        )
```

This what I have in my loop: (I don't have a clue how to remove the value and put the new one in the grid cell.

```
 function gridChange() {

    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.read();
    var count = grid.dataSource.total();
    $("#countElement").html('Encrypting ' + count + ' Lines');

    // get data from the grid
    var gridData = $("#grid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.view();
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    // loop rows
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        str = gridData[i].EntityId;
        EntityIdhash = CryptoJS.SHA256(str);

        // remove old value
        // enter new value

        console.log('EntityId: ' + gridData[i].EntityId + '\n'); 
        console.log('EntityId encrypted: ' + EntityIdhash + '\n'); 

    }

};
```

Comment: OK, so as I understand it, you make changes to the grid. Then you want to click on the "Save" button and have it run a loop through each line that you changed and save those changes?

Comment: yes @Keith, you got that right

Comment: do you use inline editing or do you have to click on a button to edit the row?

Comment: Well for a start, you don't seem to be calling the `gridChange` function from what we can see.. Unless you are initialising this event in `document.ready` or something?

Comment: @Sandman, I have the new values for editing. I just want to do it in one stroke. This function will be fired up by a button and preform the button change.

Comment: @Keith as you can see in the grid definition I use inCell edit mode.

Comment: If the data to be placed in the grid is the same structure as the "old" data, you could just call a `read()` on the `dataSource` and supply the new data as a parameter (as per [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/change-dynamically-data-in-datasource#KPDgfM3FzEaYOxvA7vCTBg) example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do (without seeing any HTML):

```
$('#save').on('click', function () {
    success();
})

function success() {
    var storedValues = [];
    var gridData = $("#grid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.data();
    for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
        if (gridData[i].EntityId) {
            storedValues.push({
                cellValue: gridData[i].EntityId,
            });
        }
    }
    var inputData = { yourVariable: JSON.stringify(storedValues) };
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/YourController/Here",
        data: inputData
    }).done(function (data) {
       // success here
            $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: in this case you change the values and store them in a array for post in the json. Te result I want is changing in the grid and after that I'll decide to save or not. This is the batch edit behaviour. P.S. there is no HTML i'm using razor syntax to create the grid.

Comment: By default, editable:true gives you in cell editing in which basing on strings or numbers, you can change instantly and when you focus off the cell, the new element remains. Is this not behaving the way it should? what happens when you make an edit to a cell?

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining myself. What I want is automatically go into each cell and change the value. After that I will decide if I'm hitting the save button.